# Working forlders disappear after power outage

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, power-supply, file-management

Good morning,

We have single board industrial computers that run Windows 7. These computers are powered with a generator through a power supply. We have an application that writes the logs and events to the HD of the computer. It opens the log file, updates it, and then closes it for each entry, However this is done up to 1 to 3 times per second (and there are of course periods of time that nothing gets written for 30s).

The problem we have is that if these computers suddenly loose power, the log file and the whole folder structure containing it will disappear and there is no way to restore them (They are not in Recycle bin and System restore cant find them. It seems that it never existed or someone Shift-Deleted the parent folder all together)

Is there a way to prevent it from happening? One thing that came to my mind is to implement a back up feature that backs up data every 5min or so automatically to prevent data loss. But still this is not a solution.

Another (unrelated) detail: We have two types of these computers. On older models, the computer had a small HDD. On power outages, we saw windows or system files disappearing (but not this issue). On newer models, everything (Windows, program, logs) is stored on a compact flash drive. This is where this specific issue happens.

Also, we are not allowed to power the computers with a UPS.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "We have an application that writes the logs and events to the HD of the computer."  Does the application open the log file, update it, and then close it for each entry, or does it open the log for writing when it starts running and keep it open until the application is closed?  If it's the latter, then you need to rewrite your application.

Comment: Thats a very good point! Let me check the code.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, it is the first method which seems to be the proper way of doing it. Please see the details in the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

## Disable Write-Caching

Since you mention that the logs are stored on a compact flash drive, you might want to try [disabling write-caching](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10392-write-caching-enable-disable.html) on that drive:

> This option is usually the best choice for storage devices that you
>   are likely to remove from the system frequently, such as USB flash
>   drives, SD, MMC, Compact Flash, or similar memory cards, and other
>   similar externally attached storage devices.
>
> 1. Open the Control Panel (icons view) in Windows 7 or Windows 8, and click on the Device Manager icon.
> 2. In Device Manger, double click on Disk drives to expand it, then double click on the listed storage device that you want to disable write caching for.
> 3. Click on the Polices tab. Under the upper Removal policy section, select (dot) Quick removal, or check the Turn off Windows write-cache buffer flushing on the device box, and click on OK.